# jQuery's append not working outside of getJSON callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, append

I'm working consolidating all my JSON calls.  I took everything out of this `$.getJSON` call and verified that my page still worked, but when I take the append and listview out, the content never appears.

This works:

```
    $.getJSON("data/rides.json",
        function(data){
          $('#myRideList').append( rideList.join(' ') );
          $('#myRideList').listview('refresh');
      });
```

but this doesn't:

```
  //  $.getJSON("data/rides.json",
  //    function(data){
          $('#myRideList').append( rideList.join(' ') );
          $('#myRideList').listview('refresh');
 //     });
```

Answer (score 5):

You're probably running the code before the DOM is ready.

The `getJSON` version will run asynchronously, giving the DOM a chance to load.

The second version will run immediately.

You can put the code in a [`.ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) handler to make sure the DOM is ready.

```
$(function() {
  //  $.getJSON("data/rides.json",
  //    function(data){
          $('#myRideList').append( rideList.join(' ') );
          $('#myRideList').listview('refresh');
 //     });
});
```

The syntax I used above is a shortcut for this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // ...
});
```

---

The simplest solutions are very often the best. As [@T.J.Crowder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157247/t-j-crowder) noted, the tried and true technique of putting your script at the bottom of the page *(or at least somewhere on the page after your desired elements)* is simple and requires no under-the-hood tricks.

```
<body>
   <!-- your HTML markup -->

   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/my/script.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Better yet, [put the script at the bottom of the document](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html). `ready` is useful for libraries and such, but for your own pages/apps, you're better off just locating the script elements at the bottom. Code in script elements [has access to all of the elements defined above it](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/closure-library-discuss/G-7Ltdavy0E) in the page source.

Comment: I agree with @T.J.Crowder. You can't beat the absolute simplicity and zero overhead of having the script at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Apparently this answered your question, please select it as an answer.